# About blockchain.info Api Usage

Tags: api, blockchain.info

1. When I got the code I use a url such as abc.com and I hope to know if I use my api in def.com will it work? If so what is the url meaning?
2. Every time it will generate wallet and if I use this API to receive bitcoin how will the coin go to my wallet?
3. When the API got bitcoin it will give me a response so my question is which should I use? There are 3 method for it.